# MatLab using drag n dop at RICHTEXT.RichtextCtrl.1

Tags: matlab, activex

I try to use drag and drop in a MatLab application using the MS ActiveX RICHTEXT.RichtextCtrl.1.

As long I put all code to a sample figure all works fine. For convenience reason I would like to use the guide. I just implemented the necessary code like below. When I try to drag a file to the ActiveX it will be handled by the ActiveX itself, e.g. the file will show up as attachment to the ActiveX. My function is not called.

Has anybody an idea to solve this problem?

```
function iTecLogfile_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to iTecLogfile (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for iTecLogfile
handles.output = hObject;
%handles.activex1.registerevent({'KeyUp', @richtextKeyUp});
handles.activex1.registerevent({'OLEDragDrop', @richtextOLEDragDrop});
set(handles.activex1,'OLEDropMode','rtfOLEDropManual');

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);
data = struct();
setappdata(handles.figure1,'data',data);
```